# WebdriveException element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please help on below:
page source:

```
<select class="standard-selection-3" onchange="SuperChanged();" size="8" multiple="multiple" name="super">
    <option value="90ddb13f-0989-4433-a17f-4b6438f02f78">windows</option>
</select>
```

functionality:
There is one section `field(name:super)` into added windows string, when clicked **"windows" "remove"** button will hilighted, then we click remove the windows string removed and then we add required string into the field.

Here I tried `driver.findElement(By.name("super")).clear();`
it says:

> WebdriveException element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Comment: source of tags:<select class="standard-selection-3" onchange="Supers();" size="8" multiple="multiple" name="super">
<option value="90ddb13f-0989-4433-a17f-4b6438f02f78">windows</option>
</select>

Comment: Can you share Website?

Comment: it is web interface gui,it requires credentials,so its not suppose to sharable
source tag:
<select class="standard-selection-3" onchange="Supers();" size="8" multiple="multiple" name="super">
<option value="90ddb13f-0989-4433-a17f-4b6438f02f78">windows</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you have posted, the element belongs to Select class, so you need to handle it like given below -

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("super")));
    select.deselectAll();
```

Comment: this is not check box field,the field behavior is ,when mouse clicked on string(windows)then one remove button highlighted then only we can remove.
q1:how can we highlight the string by click or clear it itself

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around:

```
webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);

where webElement is your driver.findElement(By.name("super"));
```

Also, please note that the above exception can also happen in the case that you have two elements using the same locator strategy so plz make sure your web element is unique in terms of objection identification.